# Looping through setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, settimeout

I'm trying to write a function which loops x times (3 in this example) through x steps (Step 1, Step 2 in this example) for x seconds (in this example, Step 1 takes 2 seconds, Step 2 takes 1 second).

So I'd like it to loop as below:

Step 1 (2 seconds)
Step 2 (1 second)
Step 1 (2 seconds)
Step 2 (1 second)
Step 1 (2 seconds)
Step 2 (1 second)

I've got the below code, but it only iterates through the loop once, and I can't work out why.

```
jQuery('input').click(function () {
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        jQuery('div').html('Step 1');
        setTimeout(function() { 
            jQuery('div').html('Step 2');
        },2000);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            jQuery('div').empty();
        },2000 + 1000);
    }
});
```

I would like the loop to continue with the same timings, but go back to the beginning after it hits `.empty();`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmyjhgvd/

Comment: @Pablo is correct, here's a fiddle that shows what he means, open up the console and see the logs fire http://jsfiddle.net/kmyjhgvd/2/

Comment: Why are you using a for loop here? If you need it to be time sensitive AVOID loops, use RECURSION. Recursive method can recall itself based on booleans/conditions and then start over again. This will be more timer accurate, (although timers even in this day and age have been known to fail with looping and recursion)

Comment: @Mike If you are specting events to happen after every second, a loop with an increasing time is not a bad idea per se, in my opinion

Comment: @Pablo there just isn't a good reason to go with loop because it is LESS predictable on run-time. A loop could fire all the timeouts very close to each other or lag between loop intervals. Recursion will give you a much more uniform timing when it comes to using timeouts and intervals, go with recursion.

Comment: @Mike: You descibe a problem that doesn't exist with a loop, but actually does exist with recursion. If you use recursion then the timing of each iteration will depend on all previous, so at the end you have accumulated a lag. With a loop all the timeouts have the same starting point so they won't accumulate a lag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop iterates 3 times, but the timeouts are always the same: 2000 and 3000, so you have created 3 identical callbacks to be executed in 2 seconds and other 3 ones to be called in three seconds. Here you have what you want, with 6 different timeouts:

http://jsfiddle.net/nsg7ny7L/1/

```
jQuery('input').click(function () {
    var time=0;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        setTimeout(function() { 
            jQuery('div').html('Step 1');
        },time++*1000);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            jQuery('div').html('Step 2');
        },time++*1000);
    }
    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('div').empty();
    },time++*1000);
});
```

PS: Make sure you understand how it works: JS is singlethreaded, so the for loop calls `setTimeout` 6 times in a row... the starting time is almost the same for all of them

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the code, but I think this should work

```
jQuery('input').click(function () {
     loopAction (3, 1, 2); // x is number of loops - s1, s2 in seconds
});

function loopAction(x, s1, s2){
   If (x>0){                 // as long as x>0 start the iteration
      jQuery('div').html('Step 1');
      setTimeout(function() { 
          jQuery('div').html('Step 2');
          setTimeout(function() {
             loopAction(x-1, s1, s2); // recursive call to self
          }, s2*1000);
      },s1*1000);
  } else {
     jQuery('div').empty();    // x>0 is false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Up to my understanding loops are not a good fit for timely controlled actions, as indicated in the comments on the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have step 1 directly in the loop without a timeout, so all three step 1 occurences will happen right away. Then you have step 2 in a timeout, but all three of those have the same time delay so they will all happen at once two seconds later. You get this at different times:

```
   0: Step 1 (i = 0)
   0: Step 1 (i = 1)
   0: Step 1 (i = 2)
2000: Step 2 (i = 0)
2000: Step 2 (i = 1)
2000: Step 2 (i = 2)
3000: empty (i = 0)
3000: empty (i = 1)
3000: empty (i = 2)
```

You would want this:

```
   0: Step 1 (i = 0)
2000: Step 2 (i = 0)
3000: Step 1 (i = 1)
5000: Step 2 (i = 1)
6000: Step 1 (i = 2)
8000: Step 2 (i = 2)
9000: empty
```

Put step 1 and step 2 in timeouts, and set the time delays so that they happen after each other, i.e. using `i * 3000` as offset. Then you can empty the element in a separate timeout after the last step:

```
jQuery('input').click(function () {
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function() { 
      jQuery('div').html('Step 1');
    }, i * 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
      jQuery('div').html('Step 2');
    }, i * 3000 + 2000);
  }
  setTimeout(function() { 
    jQuery('div').empty();
  }, 6000 + 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Method answer:

```
function recursiveSteps(config) {
    var _step = config.step;
    config.step++;

    jQuery('div').html('Step 1');
    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('div').html('Step 2');
    },2000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('div').empty();
        },3000);
    if(config.step < 3) setTimeout(function() {recursiveSteps(config);}, config.step*1000);
    //you could put an "end" step here if needed

}

jQuery('input').click(recursiveSteps);
```

Comment: Actually, it won't work: the recursive call should be in the last callback function. Here is called immediately.

Comment: Easily fixed, I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing here but if it's supposed to timeout before calling the recursion that is easily fixed by adding another timeout... There just isn't any good reason to use a loop here, recursion is better.

Comment: I mean that the function recursiveSteps calls itself immediately, so it creates the 4 callbacks in a row, creating the same issue the OP is trying to avoid

Comment: Ah, then yes it needs another timeout on the recursiveSteps call

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('input').click(function () {

    var times = 0,
        printStep1 = function(){
            JQuery('div').html('Step 1');
            setTimeout( printStep2, 1000 );
        },
        printStep2 = function(){
            JQuery('div').html('Step 2');
            if( times++ < 3 ) setTimeout( printStep1, 1000 );
        };

    printStep1();
});
```

Without JQuery:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener( "click", function () {

    var times = 0,
        printStep1 = function(){
            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'Step 1';
            setTimeout( printStep2, 1000 );
        },
        printStep2 = function(){
            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'Step 2';
            if( times++ < 3 ) setTimeout( printStep1, 1000 );
        };

    printStep1();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic method to execute a list of steps consecutively with timeouts:

```
var steps = [
    {
        timeout: 2000,
        action: function() { jQuery('div').html('Step 1'); },
    },
    {
        timeout: 1000,
        action: function() { jQuery('div').html('Step 2'); },
    },
    {
        timeout: 1000,
        action: function() { jQuery('div').empty(); },
    }
];

function executeSteps(times, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    var task = steps[index];
    if(index > 0 || times > 0) {
        if(index == 0) times--;
        task.action();
        setTimeout(function() { 
            executeSteps(times, (index + 1) % steps.length);
        }, task.timeout);
    }
}

jQuery('input').click(function () { 
    executeSteps(3);
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5sw94sx/)